# How to update bar graph data whenever array is updated in d3 v6.3.1?

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

I'm trying to update a bargraph created using d3.js to display values from a regularly updated array. Currently, I have a function d3Data that is called upon page load(using jQuery) and as a function invoked whenever buttons are clicked on the page. This d3 data updates the array and then calls another function d3New that is supposed to rerender the bar graph.

The bar graph is able to render along with the bar rectangles if hard coded data in the array is used. However, since I initialize the starting array as empty I am unable to see the rectangles as it seems my bar graph doesn't display rectangles based on updated values in this array.

Here is my logic for displaying the rectangles within the bar graph:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
.data(data)

rects.enter().append("rect")

rects.exit().remove()

rects.attr("x", function(d, i) { return (i * 2.0 + 1.3) * barWidth; })
.attr("y", function(d,i) {
    return Math.min(yScale(0), yScale(d))
})


.attr("height", function(d) {
    // the height of the rectangle is the difference between the scale value and yScale(0);
    return Math.abs(yScale(0) - yScale(d));
}) 
.attr("width", barWidth)
.style("fill", "grey")
.style("fill", function(d,i) { return color[i];})
```

I understand the enter() function intially joins the data to the rectangle elements and the exit function is used in order to remove any previous rectangle element values upon rectangle rerender. But, no rectangles are rendered to the screen and not sure why? Here is what it looks like:

[image: Bar graph]

Any help would be great

edit:

Here is some more of the two functions:

```
function d3Data() {
    var dataArray = [];
    for (var key in gradeFrequency) {
        dataArray.push(gradeFrequency[key]);
    }
    d3New(dataArray);
}
function d3New(data) {
    var height = 500;
    var width = 500;
    var margin = {left: 100, right: 10, top: 100, bottom: 20};
    var color = ["#C6C7FF", "#8E8EFC", "#5455FF", "#8E8EFC", "#C6C7FF"];

    var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
    .attr('height', height)
    .attr('width', width)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate("+ [margin.left + "," + margin.top] + ")");

    var barWidth = 30; 

    var chartHeight = height-margin.top-margin.left;  

    var xScale= d3.scaleBand()
        .domain(["A", "B", "C", "D", "F"])     
        .range([100, 450])            
        .padding([0.8]) 

    // Draw the axis
    svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(-100,300)")   
        .call(d3.axisBottom(xScale));


    var yScale = d3.scaleLinear()
    .domain([0, 1.0])
    .range([chartHeight, 0]);

    var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

    rects.enter().append("rect").merge(rects)

    rects.exit().remove()
```

Comment: I don't think you've provided enough code for anyone to even attempt to answer this.  Please update your question with enough to reproduce the issue.  In the off chance I'll get lucky update this line `rects.enter().append("rect")` to `rects = rects.enter().append("rect").merge(rects)`....

Comment: Updated to show more of both functions. I also added merge but seems it subsequent identical graphs are rendered to the page each time d3Data is called

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out how to fix my problem. Had to add:

```
 d3.selectAll("svg").remove();
```

to the start of the function in order to remove previous outdated graphs and also add the attributes for "rect" before the .exit().remove(). So instead of:

```
var rects = svg.selectAll("rect")
    .data(data)

    rects.enter().append("rect").merge(rects)

    rects.exit().remove()

    rects.attr(..).attr(..).attr(..)
```

I did:

```
rects.enter().append("rect").merge("rect").attr(..).attr(..).attr(..) and so on.

rects.exit().remove()
```

Since the attributes for the rectangles need to be updated as well they had to go before the .exit() and .remove() calls